# Run function on dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that creates some html for products. In the static way this html have `onclick` events. However this doesn't work when I create the html dynamically. The onclick event fires a function for a quantity box with "+"  and "-" symbols.

How do I make it so that it works with dynamic content? I've searched the forum but can not come with a solution. I prefer to somehow keep the function `updateQuantity` but have it work with both dynamic and static content.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Console now returns errors saying that `up` and `down` are not defined.

My script (I have beautified the code for readabillity)

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json){
  ......
 $.each(json.products, function(index, product){
   .....
   productHtml += '<div class="item-btn" data-p-vid="'+product.vid+'">
    <form action="" id="product_configure_form2" method="post" role="form">
      <div class="custom-quantity-input">
       <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
       <a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'up');" class="up quantity-btn quantity-input-up">+</a>
<a href="" class="down quantity-btn quantity-input-down">-</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'down');" class="item-add-btn-cart" title="' + getAjaxTranslation('Add to cart') + '"></a>
  </form>
</div>';

function updateQuantity(item, way){

        var inputField = $(item).closest('.custom-quantity-input').find('input');
        var quantity = parseInt(inputField.val(), 10);

        if (way == 'up'){
          if (quantity < 10000){
            quantity++;
              } else {
              quantity = 10000;
          }
        } else {
          if (quantity > 1){
            quantity--;
              } else {
              quantity = 1;
          }
        }

        inputField.val(quantity);
      }
```

Comment: You should have nice big errors in console. Open it, explore your errors and fix.

Comment: for the errors for up and down not defined, try adding slashes like \'up\' and \'down\'. Without the slashes, it escapes the string and treats it as a variable. Put slashes if you want to include it as a string.

Comment: You have some inconsistency with the link that has the down class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices suggests event delegation.

Something like this also avoids your issue with nested single quotes:

```
$(function() {
  $("#productHTMLContainer").on("click",".up, .down, .item-add-btn-cart",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateQuantity(this,$(this).hasClass("up")?"up":"down"); 
  }); 
});
```

where productHTMLContainer is whatever you insert the productHtml into.

It also seems you are not consistent with your html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'up');" class="up quantity-btn quantity-input-up">+</a>
<a href="" class="down quantity-btn quantity-input-down">-</a>
```

should it not be

```
<a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,\'up\');" class="up quantity-btn quantity-input-up">+</a>
<a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,\'down\');" class="down quantity-btn quantity-input-down">-</a>
```

???

Answer (score 0):

up and down are considered variables because you aren't escaping the quotes and your html string is wrapped with quotes.
This should work :

```
   productHtml += 
'<div class="item-btn" data-p-vid="'+product.vid+'">
       <form action="" id="product_configure_form2" method="post" role="form">
           <div class="custom-quantity-input">
               <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
               <a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,\'up\');" class="up quantity-btn quantity-input-up">+</a>
               <a href="" class="down quantity-btn quantity-input-down">-</a>
           </div>
           <a href="#" onclick="updateQuantity(this,\'down\');" class="item-add-btn-cart" title="' + getAjaxTranslation('Add to cart') + '"></a>
       </form>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change `updateQuantity(this,'down')` to `updateQuantity(this,\'down\')`
Hint: You use "'" as string delimiter, so, if you want to use symbol "'" inside this string you must escape them

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(document)` in jQuery to attach the events to the document and not to the especific element.. follow the example:

```
$(document).on('click','.item-add-btn-cart', function(e){
//run updateQuantity() here
})
```

Important using `.on` to attach the event in this case. So if you create dinamically html this event will keep working